# Find combinations in Ruby that are less than a certain number

Tags: ruby

Say I have an array [1,2,3] and I want every combination of these numbers that don't exceed 4.  So I would have [1,2,3].someMethod(4) and it would give me:

```
[1,1,1,1]
[1,1,2]
[1,3]
[2,2]
```

So far I have:

```
(1..4).flat_map{|size| [1,2,3].repeated_combination(size).to_a }
```

but this gives me every possible combinations, including the ones that exceed my given limit. Is there an good way to either only get combinations that add up to my limit?

Comment: The numbers of repeated combinations that sum to any given number is finite only if the numbers all positive. Can we assume that is the case? Where you say, "don't exceed 4", I believe you mean "whose sum equals 4". Correct?

Comment: All answers so far only work when the given array contains a `1`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland What do you mean? Why should the solutions not work without `1`?

Comment: I assume the array contains positive integers and `4` was chosen as the size of largest array in the array returned only because `4*1 #=> 4`. If the array did not contain a `1` and `4` were not the specified sum,  determing the size of the largest array whose sum equals (or is not more than) the given total is a non-trivial (and I expect np-complete) problem.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I guess the question is related to the [coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem). Therefore `[2,3,4]` for the value `4` results in `[[2,2],[4]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
results = (1..4).each.with_object([]) do |size, results| 
  [1,2,3].repeated_combination(size) do |combo|
    results << combo if combo.reduce(:+) == 4
  end
end

p results

--output:--
[[1, 3], [2, 2], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Parameterizing the algorithm:

```
def do_stuff(values, target_total)
  (1..target_total).each.with_object([]) do |size, results| 
    values.repeated_combination(size) do |combo|
      results << combo if combo.reduce(:+) == 4
    end
  end
end

p do_stuff([1, 2, 3], 4)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
arr = [1,2,3]

(arr+[0]).repeated_combination(4).select { |a| a.reduce(:+) == 4 }.map { |a| a - [0] }
   #=> [[1, 3], [2, 2], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Change `==` to `<=` if desired.

This answer, like the others, assumes `arr` contains natural numbers, including `1`.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter out the arrays you don't want by using the `select` method. Just select all the arrays that have a sum `==` 4 (the sum is calculated by the `inject` method).

```
all_arrs = (1..4).flat_map do |size|
  [1,2,3].repeated_combination(size).to_a
end

valid_arrs = all_arrs.select do |arr|
  arr.inject { |a, b| a + b } == 4
end

print valid_arrs

# Output:
# [[1, 3], [2, 2], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: Good answer. However the OP only wants combinations that equal the required limit. Also needs it to be wrapped up into a definition that can be used (extending the Array class maybe?).

Comment: Whoops, fixed that just now thanks for the catch. And I see your point, but I think that part should be left to OP.

Answer (score 1):

A recursive approach.

```
def some_method(a, n)
  return [[]] if n == 0

  a.select { |e| e <= n }.\
    flat_map { |e| some_method(a,n-e).map { |es| ([e] + es).sort } }.\
    sort.\
    uniq
end

p some_method([1,2,3], 4)
# => [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 2]]
```

EDIT: Here is another recursive version without filtering duplicates but with opposite order. I added comments to make it clearer.

```
def some_method(a, n)
  return [[]] if n == 0           # bottom (solution) found
  return [] if a.empty? || n < 0  # no solution

  max = a.max
  # search all solutions with biggest value
  l = some_method(a, n-max).map { |e| [max] + e }
  # search all solutions without biggest value
  r = some_method(a-[max],n)

  l + r
end

p some_method([1,2,3], 4)
# => [[3, 1], [2, 2], [2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: You need to make some adjustments to get the correct output.

Comment: Thanks, @7stud. Fixed it but guess there is an better way to avoid duplicates.